# pause spritekit scene and show "paused" label

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I want to show a "paused" `SKLabelNode` when someone clicks on the screen and therefore pauses the sprite kit game.

So I have in `touchesBegan` ->

```
[self.pausedLabel setHidden:!self.pausedLabel.hidden];
[self.scene.view setPaused:!self.scene.view.paused];
```

The Game is paused correctly but the `SKLabelNode` is not shown (scene not rendered before paused?!)
If I add a `NSTimer` for pausing the scene the label is shown, but then the game continues for that timer-time.

Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SKAction for this. You can use +runBlock: to add the code related to hiding the label, and then use the -runAction method with the completion handler to pause the scene. The runBlock: method may return immediately, but this way, the screen manages to update before the scene is paused.

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [self.pausedLabel setHidden:!self.pausedLabel.hidden];
}];

[self.pausedLabel runAction:action completion:^{
    [self.scene.view setPaused:!self.scene.paused];
}];
```

Comment: this is not working, because actions are not executed when the view is paused. So it will never resume when the user clicks again..

Comment: I've edited your answer. Now it is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a state ivar to determine if the scene should update its content or not. 
When you click the button set this state to `PAUSE` and in your scene frame update loop test the state.

```
if (_state != PAUSE) {// Use enum for the state var
    // Update scene objects
}
```

when your button is clicked:

- Add pause label to scene
- Set state to `PAUSE`

The benefits of this approach is that it allows you to decide exactly what will happen on pause (opposing to pausing the whole scene). You can animate a cool background while in pause or do anything you'd like as this is totally in your control

Comment: this would work, but then I will use CPU-power even the user paused the game (about 20%). I think this isn't the best practice..

Comment: You are not over using the CPU because the main loop will still be running and rendering all your nodes and do the logic stuff. Its like saying the an empty Scene will overuse the CPU which is incorrect